# How to divide words into syllables?

Tags: syllables

For example "my class" - are the syllables in this "mike" and "lass" or "my" and then "class", another one is "recent" - are the syllables "reese" and "ent" or "ree"  and "sent"?

Comment: Do you know the definition of syllable? *any of the units into which a word is divided, containing a vowel sound and usually one or more consonants* -> So "*my c*" and "*lass*" is not possible by definition...

Comment: @Em1: [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/syllable) says "A unit of spoken language consisting of a single uninterrupted sound formed by a vowel, diphthong, or syllabic consonant alone, or by any of these sounds preceded, followed, or surrounded by one or more consonants."

Comment: True, my class may not be applicable (however @DavidSchwartz makes a good point). How about my example of "recent"?

Comment: He just said the same as I did with different words and [recent](http://www.wordcentral.com/cgi-bin/student?book=Student&va=recent) is general reference.

Comment: And if your question is about *how can I learn correct syllabication* then I think it's actually just *feeling how to do* or learning them. I never learned syllabication of English word but, though, I'm able to split *recent* correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different syllabic boundaries in various dictionaries?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21529/different-syllabic-boundaries-in-various-dictionaries)

Comment: Are you asking how to find syllabic boundaries in words you don't already know how to pronounce? Or how to deduce the syllables from words you do know how to pronounce?

Comment: In English, syllables rarely move across the boundaries of words. (Of course, now somebody will bring up *try-na* as the spoken abbreviation for *trying to,* where it's clear that they have.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to deduce correct syllabication from the spelling of the words? Putting aside the fact that English is a horrible language to spell, syllables work on the sound level. So you pronounce the word first and separate it later. You need to do all of that in your ear. Your eyes won't help you.

recent -> ˈriːsənt -> ˈriː + sənt