# Context-specific hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation, heteronyms

Are there any heteronyms in English with different hyphenation patterns for line breaking? That is, is there any sequence of letters which can be interpreted as two different words with different pronunciations such that it would be generally considered appropriate to hyphenate at a particular point for line breaking only if one of the words was meant, not the other?

I’ve scanned through lists of heteronyms, but nothing’s popped out. As far as I know there are no reference works which address this question. The underlying question, I suppose, is whether it’s always possible to hyphenate purely mechanically, with a dictionary of hyphenations and without considering context.

Example from a comment: Suppose there were some word *frochouse*, which would be pronounced "fro-SHOOS" and could be hyphenated as *fro-chouse*, and another word *frochouse* which would be pronounced "FROCK-hows" and could be hyphenated as *froc-house*. That would be an example, if not for the fact that both are made-up words.

Comment: The difference between *resign* and *re-sign*?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with it, but [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resign) says you can hyphenate *resign* (relegate, give up) after "re". So it wouldn't count?

Comment: @Henry *re-sign* can be hyphenated in the same way as *resign* (and vice versa).

Comment: There is a distinction between hyphenation at the end of a line to break words for layout purposes and general hyphenation to indicate meaning and pronunciation.

Comment: @Henry good point, I’m specifically focusing on hyphenation for line-breaking purposes.

Comment: Periodic (at [fixed] intervals) / periodic (compare perchloric) are probably candidates. But this is of fringe interest. More important is that 'heteronym' is polysemous; 'boot' and 'trunk' are heteronyms, as are 'footpath' and 'sidewalk'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Let me know if you have difficulty figuring out which meaning is intended.

Comment: I'm with @Henry, but for re-creation and recreation.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I think both of those hyphenate as re-cre-a-tion. (Unless you are suggesting that one form must have a hyphen after the first e? Then they wouldn’t be heteronyms.)

Comment: Hyphenation has zero to do with meaning. There is no way to tell - other than context - whether the meaning is re-sign (to sign again) and resign (leave a position).

Comment: @Lambie exactly. Which makes it potentially the case that there’s some word, say “frochouse”, which would be pronounced “fro-SHOOS” and could be hyphenated as fro-chouse, and another word “frochouse” which would be pronounced “FROCK-hows” and could be hyphenated as “froc-house”. I’m just not sure whether there’s any instance which is real words rather than made up ones.

Comment: No, no, you don't change hyphenation based on pronunciation as you say in your comment. You are attempting to discount what I said. Homophones are hyphenated the same way. There would be no difference.

Comment: Of interest, perhaps: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/458817/hyphenation-end-of-line-division-of-germany-and-some-other-common-words

Comment: @Lambie I'm not asking about homophones. It sounds like you might be addressing the case of British English, where hyphenation is (usually) based on affixes rather than pronunciation. (I'd be happy for examples from any dialect, of course.)

Comment: Oxford Dictionary: each of two or more words that are spelled identically but have different sounds and meanings, such as tear meaning “rip” and tear meaning “liquid from the eye.”. Those would be hyphenated the same way. Tearing in both cases. Hyphenated the same way.

Comment: Right, that is an example of heteronyms, but not of ones that are hyphenated differently. I'm looking for examples (if any) of heteronyms that *are* hyphenated differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*refuse* the verb breaks as *re-fuse*.
*refuse* the noun breaks as *ref-use*.

*attribute* the verb breaks as *at-trib-​ute*.
*attribute* the noun breaks as *at-​tri-bute*.

*resume* the verb breaks as *re-sume*.
*resume* the noun breaks as *re-su-me*.

*sake* the beverage breaks as *sa-ke*.
The other *sakes* can’t break.

<sub>Source: [Merriam Webster—refuse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refuse)</sub>

Here are a few more:

*crooked* the adjective breaks as *crook-ed*.
*crooked* the verb can’t break.

*wicked* the adjective breaks as *wick-ed*.
*wicked* the verb can’t break.

*dogged* the adjective breaks as *dog-ged*.
*dogged* the verb can’t break.

<sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

So, no, without context, you can’t decide where or if to break.

Comment: Goodness, I really wasn't expecting there to be so *many* examples. My powers of brainstorming are clearly not what they once were. ;-) The -ed pattern is interesting, and "refuse" is particularly interesting given the shared etymology and not being a loan-word.

Comment: Just added another; I’m sure there are more!

Comment: A few more in here: https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2010/04/snappy-endings.html